# how to append an array of dictionaries to another array

Tags: ios, swift4

I tried to append an array of dictionaries which are coming from server to a globally declared array.but i am getting an error like "Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'"if anyone helps me would be great.Thanks in advance

```
var pro = [[String:Any]]()

    var productsdetails = Array<Any>()
    productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "products") as! Array
     print("response\(productsdetails)")
               self.pro = self.pro.append(productsdetails)
                    print(self.pro)
```

Comment: var productsdetails = Array<[String:Any]>()

Comment: still getting same error "Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'"

Comment: At which line??

Comment: " self.pro = self.pro.append(productsdetails)"

Answer (score 1):

Use this code like below, i hope this works

```
var pro = [[String:Any]]()

if let productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "products") as? [[String:Any]] {
    print("response\(productsdetails)")
    self.pro.append(productsdetails)
    print(self.pro)
}
```

Comment: " self.pro = self.pro.append(productsdetails)" after using this code ,then also getting same

Comment: this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here pro is appending a new element [String : String]]

to solve this iterate

```
var pro = [[String:Any]]()

if let productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "products") as? [[String: Any]] {
    for details in productsdetails {
       pro.append(details)
    }

}
```

or you may use directly `self.pro = productsdetails` if you not to want iterate

**image shows [String : String] as I have used [String : String] instead of [String : Any]*

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this: (Swift-4.2)**

```
var data: [String: Any] = [
    "key1": "example value 1",
    "key2": "example value 2",
    "items": []
]

for index in 1...3 {

    let item: [String: Any] = [
        "key": "new value"
    ]

    // get existing items, or create new array if doesn't exist
    var existingItems = data["items"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()

    // append the item
    existingItems.append(item)

    // replace back into `data`
    data["items"] = existingItems
}
```

Answer same as: [Append to array in [String: Any] dictionary structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518492/append-to-array-in-string-any-dictionary-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your response which has key products? As there is mismatch with the variable pro and productdetails. As i see pro holds values as "Array of Dictionary with key as String type and Value as Any type" which again has Array above it and productdetails is expecting Array of Any type not the Array of Dictionary Type. Assuming your products has Array of String Type or can be even a class object type you can do it as below.

```
var pro = Array<Any>() //Or You can make Array<String>() or Array<CustomClass>()

var userdata:[String:[String]] = ["products":["One","Two","Three"]]

var productsdetails = Array<Any>()
productsdetails = userdata["products"] ?? []
print("response\(productsdetails)")
pro.append(productsdetails)
```